# rails bundle install gives permission denied error

Tags: git, ruby-on-rails-4, bundler

I installed **rvm** and **ruby** as **root**. Then created a **new directory** as **root** and change the ownership (recursively `chown -R`) from **root to me**. After that, I logged in and `cd` to the **new directory** and cloned a rails project from a remote repository. Everything works as expected but if I try **bundle install** it keeps on giving the below mentioned error.

**error: cannot open .git/FETCH_HEAD: Permission denied**

I am the owner of the mentioned directory and all its contents including `.git`.

Answer (score 1):

Check if you have enough permissions on the .git/ directory. You should have write permissions. You can set them with the following command

Go to your project folder:

```
chown -R youruser .git/
```